# Passing arguments to events in backbone

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

First of all, I did some search and no answer on stackoverflow/google provided me the thing I wanted.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
//in the view
this.collection.on("add",triggerthis)
this.collection.add(predefinedModel)
triggerthis: function(a, b, c, d){
    //etc.
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to pass an argument on add and receive the argument in triggerthis. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the `triggerthis` event handler will be called by the backbone event code, where do you expect those extra argument will come from?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how this works. I suppose I can call an anonymous function in on() that calls triggerthis inside, but I'm not sure if this is the good way to proceed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't do this the way you want without using undocumented features.

If we have a look at [`Collection#add`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L598), we'll see this:

```
add: function(models, options) {
  //...
  for (i = 0, l = add.length; i < l; i++) {
    (model = add[i]).trigger('add', model, this, options);
  }
  //...
}
```

Note the fourth argument to `trigger`. And if we look at the documented interface for [`trigger`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger):

> **trigger** `object.trigger(event, [*args])`
>
> Trigger callbacks for the given **event**, or space-delimited list of events. Subsequent arguments to **trigger** will be passed along to the event callbacks.

So the `add` will call the listeners as `f(model, collection, options)` where `options` is the same `options` what you passed to `Collection#add`. The result is that if you do this:

```
this.collection.add(predefinedModel, { undocumented: 'arguments' })
```

then you could do this in your callback:

```
triggerthis: function(model, collection, options) {
    console.log(options.undocumented);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bqWwQ/

You could of course tunnel a whole array or object through `options` this way.

The third argument for `"add"` events isn't documented (at least not that I can find), the closest thing to documentation for this is a note in the [0.3.3 Changelog entry](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> The ubiquitous `options` argument is now passed as the final argument to all `"change"` events.

I wouldn't recommend this approach but it is there if you need it; you will of course need to cover this in your test suite and you'll need to make sure you don't use any keys in `options` that Backbone will be using.

---

A safer approach would be to attach some extra properties to the model:

```
model.baggage = { some: 'extra stuff };
```

and then peel that off in the callback:

```
triggerthis: function(model, collection) {
    var baggage = model.baggage;
    delete model.baggage;
    //...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/M3UaH/

You could also use different callbacks for different purposes or pass your extra parameters as full blown model attributes.

There's also [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
this.collection.on("add", _.bind(function(collection, model, extra) { ... }, context, collection, model, 'whatever you want'));
```

but that will bind arguments from left to right so you'll have to specify *all* the arguments that your callback will need.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jUpJz/

Answer (score 6):

If the values passed to the function are always the same, you can [partially apply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) it using `_.bind` (or the native `Function.bind` if available)

E.g. Where you're binding the handler to `add` (assuming `triggerThis` is a method in your view):

```
this.collection.on('add', _.bind(this.triggerThis, this, a, b, c, d));
```

The definition of `triggerThis`:

```
triggerThis: function(a, b, c, d /*, model, collection, options - if you need them*/) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to pass arguments to an *individual* add call, you can use the second `options` parameter to `add` and then handle that in your event handler.

E.g.

```
this.collection.on('add', this.triggerThis, this);
this.collection.add(model, {
  someCustomValue: 'hello';
});
```

Then in your handler:

```
triggerThis: function(model, collection, options) {
  var val = options.someCustomValue;
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the third `options` argument isn't exactly documented.

Comment: True, though in one of the changelog entries (for 0.9.0) it mentions that "Within a collection's add and remove events, the index of the model being added or removed is now available as options.index." so I assume it's probably not going away anytime soon.

Comment: The `options` argument to the callbacks is sort of a gray area, the docs sort of talk around it without coming right out saying that it is there. I suspect that it will get legitimatized at some point. I just though it was worth mentioning that there are some caveats.